# Which sets use "white brick 2 x 1 with a skid"

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

let me ask you for a partnumber of part I have found at home and cannot join to any set.
The color is white - brick 1 x 2 with added ramp.

I have the part twice, so I am looking for the set where it was used.

[image]

Comment: Do the added blue patterns in the picture have any relevance to your question ? Do your parts maybe have a pattern or sticker on them ? If so, could you provide a picture of the actual part(s) you're looking at ?

Comment: The blue markings indicate missing material.

Answer (score 17):

Looking at the blue markings in your image it will probably be [2823 - Technic Forklift Fork](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2823#T=C).
[image: 2823 - Technic Forklift Fork]

It is used in white in [four sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2823&in=S).

Answer (score 3):

That part type is a 6x1 curved slope.

Have a look at https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=curved+slope+6x1&color=1&tab=A#T=A - it lists that piece type, in white, that have either a printed pattern or sticker. See if any of the entries match what you have. Alternately, see if you can provide a photo of the piece in question, or a link to a photo hosted elsewhere.

Comment: That was not the question.

Comment: @Davidw : while it's likely the blue markings indicate cutouts, they could also indicate a pattern, or might be entirely irrelevant. In the latter two cases, this answer is appropriate. We need the op to disambiguate the question to be 100% sure.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker They clarified the meaning of the markings in the comments...

Comment: @Davidw : the comment you refer to was posted by a different user. Unless that user has inside information, it appears to be just their best guess presented as fact.